# What to pass as string argument to constructor?

Tags: c#

I have the following situation:

```
protected MobileWalletRequestBase(XmlDocument xmlDoc, string request)
{
    _xmlDoc = xmlDoc;
}

protected MobileWalletRequestBase()
    : this(new XmlDocument(), ?)
{
    _xmlDoc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><request/>");
}
```

What should I write in second constructor in order to pass string value?

Comment: you can pass `null` as string value

Comment: The real question is: what *should* the default value be? OTOH, as you're not accounting for `request` in the base constructor anyway, it doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: There should be number represented as string.

Comment: `string.Empty`, `null` or `"Your string is not used"` what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a default argument:

```
protected MobileWalletRequestBase(XmlDocument xmlDoc, string request="foo")
{
    // but you're not using request in here, unclear what's needed
    _xmlDoc = xmlDoc;  
}

protected MobileWalletRequestBase()
    : this(new XmlDocument())   // don't say anything
{
    _xmlDoc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><request/>");
}
```